# "text/plain" content type header for x-www-form-urlencoded content?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, authentication, oauth2

I'm getting the following response body and header from `https://stackoverflow.com/oauth/access_token` when attempting to
exchange an oauth code for a token:

`<DEBUG> [00:30:03] my-app - content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
<DEBUG> [00:30:03] my-app - response: access_token=<redacted>&expires=86400`

I'm writing an oauth2 client not specific to stack exchange and I'm not sure how to handle this kind of response in a generic way, since it's neither JSON, nor does the content-type give me any useful indication on how to interpret the content without looking at the content itself.

Should the content type be `x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Comment: No. As already explained, `x-www-form-urlencoded` is not for server responses.  You know what to expect because (A) [The docs tell you exactly](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication) and (B), the page is in direct response to your `POST`.  ... Also note that other general clients have no troulbe handling the Stack exchange API, even though it is non-conforming. (Nevertheless, [the linked bug](https://stackapps.com/q/4132) should be resolved.) **Update:** Turns out the FR/Bug was silently resolved last year. See the duplicate question.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of my own answer pointing out the new json endpoint in the doc. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The question is either not completely clear or a duplicate. You may need to post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

According to the [OAuth 2.0 Authorization spec (RFC 6749), section 5.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-5.1):

> The parameters are included in the entity-body of the HTTP response
> using the "application/json" media type as defined by [RFC4627]

So, apparently the `content-type` should be `application/json;charset=UTF-8`.?.
That would seem to make sense.

Also note that [officially](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/x-www-form-urlencoded):

> Restrictions on usage :
> This type (x-www-form-urlencoded) is only intended to be used to describe HTML **form submission** payloads.

<sup>(Emphasis added)</sup>
**That is, `x-www-form-urlencoded` is only for submissions to the server, not responses to the client.**

---

---

Your app code (and the API) appears to be working properly, you are getting an `access_token` in the body.

And yes, the body is `text/plain` (transmitted via SSL). That *might* be permissible.  See *[Stack Exchange OAuth2, explicit access-token response format does not adhere to RFC6749 standard](https://stackapps.com/questions/4132/stack-exchange-oauth2-explicit-access-token-response-format-does-not-adhere-to)* and see [RFC 6750](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750).

The purpose of `x-www-form-urlencoded` is to package data in an unambiguous way that removes conflicts with the HTTP protocols (reserved characters, etc.).  It is separate but: related to, more compact than, more strict than, and more specialized than HTML -- which is what the server uses to send back the response.

Since a server's response to a form POST is expected to be valid HTML, there is no need for form or URL encoding.
You can think of x-www-form-urlencoded as a kind of "micro format".

Comment: sorry, what isn't clear about the question? is there skepticism about whether the API actually sends back the content-type and response as stated?

Comment: I don't understand why the stackexchange API would use this custom non-standard response format instead of a standard JSON object that most REST api libraries understand. Also inconsistent with most of the rest of the API which uses JSON.

Comment: @user84207, the question was not clear because (1) you were getting an `access_token`, which is the whole point, (2) the question shows confusion about the purpose and use of `x-www-form-urlencoded`, (3) you listed no actual practical problem.  Contrast this to the linked bug report.