# PLACEHOLDER: Propose Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange as OAuth provider to demo-eleventy-serverless-oautn

Tags: app, placeholder, users, oauth2, website

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image: Login with Stack Overflow - Eleventy Serverless OAuth Demo]

[image: Secure page - Eleventy Serverless OAuth Demo]

### About

Eleventy is a static website generator. On version 1 it added support for severless functions. During the beta, the Eleventy maintainer created a demo for using serverles functions to add OAuth support to a static site including Netlify, GitHub and others but not Stack Exchange / Stack Overflow as OAuth providers. This is about a fork of the demo repo to add Stack Exchange / Stack Overflow as a *proof of concept*.

#### License

TBD

#### Download

Website: https://serene-bonbon-b699e0.netlify.app/

#### Platform

Web browsers: Chrome, Firefox, Safari. Other browsers like Brave and Edge might work to.

### Contact

I created this website / repo from the main branch of https://github.com/11ty/demo-eleventy-serverless-oauth.

### Code

- Node.js
- GitHub
- Netlify
- Eleventy
- Nunjucks
- JavaScript
- HTML
- CSS

#### Highlights

- The Stack Exchange Authentication uses https://stackoverflow.com as the token host.
- To get the user data, use https://api.stackexchange.com, including the **access token** taken from the OAuth flow and the **key** from the app registration.
- To get the access token, I'm using https://stackoverflow.com/oauth/access_token/json.
- I added the **client id** and **client secret** to the Netlify environment variables as instructed on the referred demo's README.md and the **key** above. I added several if statements to handle using Stack Exchange as an OAuth provider and adapted `secure.njk` to handle the Stack Exchange user profile data.

## Now

I am working on cleaning the code.

## Related

### [app](/questions/tagged/app)

- [PLACEHOLDER - Jardín Digital de Rubén](https://stackapps.com/q/10533/105187)

### [support](/questions/tagged/support)

- [Stack Exchange OAuth2, explicit access-token response format does not adhere to RFC6749 standard](https://stackapps.com/q/4132/105187)
- [How to register a Stack App with explicit OAuth 2.0 flow to a third party site?](https://stackapps.com/q/8398/105187)